# Transfert a Zend Project to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework

I have a project made using Zend. My boss asked me to change the technology to Symfony 2.7.

Is there a way to transfer the project ? Or to take some files into Symfony ? Or should I begin all the project from scratch using Symfony ?

Thanks !

Comment: You'll probably need to start from scratch. Hope it's not a big project.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, not funny to start from scratch but no problem :)

Comment: Yeah. It's a little lame of your boss to have you build something and then switch the underlying tech like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way*** I can think of that would allow you to automatically transfer a project from `Zend Framework 1` to `Symfony2`.

- You would have to start all over again, from scratch.

My boss made me do that, there was this app written in `C`, `Python`, `Perl`, `Bash` and so on and I wanted to use `Zend Framework 1.12`. I had to develop the project from scratch. That means you would have to read the code in the original technology and apply the same logic within a `Symfony2` app.

As you have yourself developed the original app, you shouldn't encounter that many problems in order to use the same logic. If you do, don't hesitate to come back to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and we will be more than happy to help you ([providing that your ask On Topic good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

<sup>*if you ever develop this kind of functionnality, you'd be the king and able to stop working altogether :)</sup>